# np.concatenate error...ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions

Tags: python, numpy, dataframe

My code words fine until I try to load in my headers to the data frame. It appears to be an issue with np.concatenate.

I've tried transposing the array to see if it is in the incorrect direction.

```
print("\n")
print("Prediction")

Y = vectorizer.transform(df['plot_keywords'].astype('U'))

prediction = model.predict(Y)

df_tmp = np.concatenate([df, pd.DataFrame(np.transpose(prediction.astype(np.int32)), columns=['cluster_plot_keywords'])], axis=1)


#!!!this is where the error is, caused by the np.concatenate!!!
df = pd.DataFrame(df_tmp, columns=[np.concatenate([df.columns.values,'cluster_plot_keywords'])])
```

Expected results would be I can write df and print the data frame.

I am receiving the following error while creating the headers for the data frame:

```
ValueError    Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-42a155bf519f> in <module>
      7 
      8 #!!!this is where the error is, caused by the np.concatenate!!!
----> 9 df = pd.DataFrame(df_tmp, columns=[np.concatenate([df.columns.values,'cluster_plot_keywords'])])

ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions
```

If I print df_tmp, it does output the array properly, but not as a data frame, which is why I am trying to load in the columns:

```
array([['Color', 'James Cameron', 723.0, ..., 1.78, 33000, 0],
       ['Color', 'Gore Verbinski', 302.0, ..., 2.35, 0, 0],
       ['Color', 'Sam Mendes', 602.0, ..., 2.35, 85000, 0],
       ...,
       ['Color', 'Benjamin Roberds', 13.0, ..., nan, 16, 2],
       ['Color', 'Daniel Hsia', 14.0, ..., 2.35, 660, 2],
       ['Color', 'Jon Gunn', 43.0, ..., 1.85, 456, 1]], dtype=object)
```

Comment: It seems you're trying to concatenate `df.columns.values` with a string, `'cluster_plot_keywords'`. Maybe you meant something like `predictions['cluster_plot_keywords']`?

Comment: `np.concatenate` is a `numpy` function.  It turns the inputs into `ndarray`, and returns a `ndarray`.  That's what you see with `df_tmp`. Shouldn't you be using some `pandas` function to combine or merge two dataframes?  And in the 2nd use, don't you want `columns` to a be a `list` of strings?  Again, why use `np.concatenate`?  What is `df.columns.values`?   list? array? string?

Comment: A list join of column names: `df.columns.tolist()+df_temp.columns.tolist()`

Answer (score 0):

In

```py
np.concatenate([df.columns.values,'cluster_plot_keywords'])
```

you are trying to concatenate an array-like object (`df.columns.values`) with a string, `'cluster_plot_keywords'` (which is "interpreted" as 0-dimensional array). It seems like a typo; maybe you meant something like

```py
np.concatenate([df.columns.values, prediction['cluster_plot_keywords']])
```

or

```py
np.concatenate([df.columns.values, df['cluster_plot_keywords']])
```

?

But I can't tell for sure without knowing more about what exactly `'cluster_plot_keywords'` is (along with `df`, `prediction` and their respective contents).